# Facing issues while running Chainlink node on XRPL EVM Sidechain network

Tags: evm, nodes, chainlink, oracles, rpc

Basically, I’m trying to [run a **Chainlink node**](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/v1/running-a-chainlink-node) on [XRPL EVM Sidechain](https://opensource.ripple.com/docs/evm-sidechain/intro-to-evm-sidechain/) network.

Here's the content of the `config.toml` file that I'm using:

```
[Log]
Level = 'warn'

[WebServer]
AllowOrigins = '\*'
SecureCookies = false

[WebServer.TLS]
HTTPSPort = 0

[[EVM]]
ChainID = '1440002'
MinContractPayment = '0 link'

[[EVM.Nodes]]
Name = 'Ripple EVM Sidechain'
WSURL = 'wss://ws-evm-poa-sidechain.peersyst.tech'
HTTPURL = 'https://rpc-evm-sidechain.xrpl.org'
```

It’s running fine for a while giving this warning:

```
[WARN] Chain length supplied for re-org detection was shorter than EvmFinalityDepth. Re-org protection is not working properly. This could indicate a problem with the remote RPC endpoint, a compatibility issue with a particular blockchain, a bug with this particular blockchain, heads table being truncated too early, remote node out of sync, or something else. If this happens a lot please raise a bug with the Chainlink team including a log output sample and details of the chain and RPC endpoint you are using. txmgr/confirmer.go:928 chainLength=1 evmChainID=1440002 evmFinalityDepth=50 logger=EVM.1440002.Txm.Confirmer nConsecutiveBlocksChainTooShort=22
```

Then, after sometime, it's escalated to this critical error:

```
[CRIT] RPC endpoint detected out of sync; but cannot disable this connection because there are no other RPC endpoints, or all other RPC endpoints are dead. Chainlink is now operating in a degraded state and urgent action is required to resolve the issue client/node_lifecycle.go:208 evmChainID=1440002 logger=EVM.1440002.Node.Lifecycle.Alive noNewHeadsTimeoutThreshold=180 node=(primary)Ripple EVM Sidechain:wss://ws-evm-poa-sidechain.peersyst.tech:https://rpc-evm-sidechain.xrpl.org nodeName=Ripple EVM Sidechain nodeTier=primary pollFailureThreshold=5 pollInterval=10 stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/v2/core/chains/evm/client.(*node).aliveLoop
```

I'll be really grateful, if anyone can help me out with this.